# output on the printf

Tags: c++, c

is there anyone who can give me a vital and simple explanation im trying to understand this program below its about the printf in c programming here is the code......

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main()
   {
    int a,b;
    float c;
      a = 1;
      b = 2;
      c = 3.;

    printf("%d %d %f\n",a ,b , c);
    printf("%d %f %f\n",a ,b , c);
    printf("%f %d %f\n",a ,b , c);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",a ,b , c);
    printf("%f %d %d\n",a ,b , c);
   return o;

    }
```

the output is

```
1  2  3.000000
1  0.000000  0.000000
0.000000  0  0.000000
1  2  0
0.000000  0  1074266112
```

im perfectly clear about the first printf's output
but why does the second printf outputs
`1  0.000000  0.000000`

instead of `1  0.000000  3.000000`

third printf `0.000000  0  3.000000`

fifth printf `0.000000  2  0.000000`

Comment: The 2nd `printf` could as well print "Hello, World!" ... or format your hard disk ... or make lemon juice ooze out of the USB port :)

Comment: where's `o` defined? You cannot return some undefined object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of all the `printf()` statements except the first one is **undefined**. You therefore cannot expect them to behave in any particular way.

To fix this, you need to cast the numeric arguments to `printf()` so that their types match the format specifier. The compiler does not perform this conversion automatically, although some good compilers would issue a warning to alert you to the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an `int` to `printf()` and tell it to treat it as a `float`, you get the garbage out corresponding to the garbage in (GIGO).  Basically, neither `printf()` nor the compiler can do any conversions for you. You have to get it right.  You must supply arguments that match the format specification.  These comments apply to all the `printf()` and `scanf()` families of functions.

If you use GCC and string literals as the format strings (as in your example), you will get compiler warnings about type mismatches.  Pay heed and fix them; the compiler knows more than you do.  If you're using a different compiler that does not give such warnings, find one (such as GCC) that does - and use it.  And make sure you turn the warnings on - and that your code compiles without emitting any warnings.

You are invoking 'undefined behaviour' with the second and subsequent statements, which means any and all answers (and other behaviours, including crashes and reformatting your disk) are acceptable responses by the system.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into **undefined behavior**. The runtime expects a `float` and you give it an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand above answers, and give a clue as to what is causing the undefined behavior.  On your platform, floats have a different size than ints, so printf() is wrong not only about the type of its arguments, but also about where they are in memory.  So in the second line, printf is not looking at the start of the float when it prints the third value; it is looking somewhere else.

Comment: What platforms have `sizeof(int) != sizeof(float)`?  On the vast majority of desktop, laptop, server systems, `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` and both are 4.  However, of course, the `float` values are promoted to `double` in the variable portion of the argument list, and then you get misalignments because `sizeof(int) != sizeof(double)` on most platforms.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- Right, I forgot about float promotion.  I'll note that in 16-bit systems (like DOS with small memory model) ints are smaller than floats.